# How to turn off warning that a property has been auto-synthesized in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang, llvm

Xcode automatically synthesizes properties now. However, for each of my properties I now get a warning stating:

```
>>> Autosynthesized property 'myProperty' will use synthesized instance variable '_myProperty' ...
```

How do I turn off these warnings?

#### Edit

I misread the compiler warning and thus formulated the wrong question for the title. However, I will leave the title unchanged in the assumption that other people might make the same (actual) mistake I did.

CRD's answer pointed out the true nature of the warning for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably *should not* turn them off.

The warnings are telling you that there is an instance variable `myProperty` but that the auto-synthesized property will use the variable `_myProperty`. If you add an `@synthesize myProperty`, as you used to, then the property *will use* the `myProperty` instance variable.

If anywhere in your code you refer to the variable `myProperty` thinking it is the value of the property then your code will be wrong.

Either remove or rename your instance variables (or add `@synthesize` directives) and your warnings will go.

Comment: Up-voted and accepted: the warning did not mean what I thought it meant.

Comment: +1 In my case I had made my `@property` as I normally do but had also the same property inside the `@interface` section of my .h as an artifact from earlier before I decided to switch to `@property` ... oops!

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Build Settings > Warnings - Objective C > Implicit Synthesized Properties`
and set the option to `NO`

Comment: I up-voted the answer for correctly answering my literal question. However, I'm going to accept CRD's answer for being correct in terms of what I actually needed (i.e. CRD read the warning message properly and I didn't).

Comment: Better to fix the warning than to silence it.